# How do I DM the Red Box encounter 4: The Trial?

Tags: dnd-4e

So I've played this adventure with some friends a few times and tomorrow we are planning to have a big adventure with multiple groups. The only problem I've encountered during the Red Box is this puzzle-esque encounter.

Can anyone that used the Red Box confirm or deny the following:

1. PC's are not allowed to know their movement type(knight/king/rook)
2. PC's can roll a check to see their movement type is limited(?)
3. PC's can try to finish the encounter without bloodshed.
4. After making 1(only one?!) false move on the board, the enemies wake up.

I just want to make sure I have the right idea, which pretty much is; This encounter might look like a puzzle but it is almost surely a battle encounter. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

1. PC's are allowed to know their movement types once they've positioned themselves.
2. Didn't get that tbh.
3. Its possible to complete the encounter without the statues coming to life.
4. It takes one false move to activate the statues, then the PC's would have to roll initiative.

That's right, its sort of a puzzle that leads to a combat encounter. Because non-combat encounters involve skills rather than combat.

Comment: This answer is short on support for the statements it gives. Could you quote or otherwise show why these four things are true, rather than just "tell"?

Comment: I would definitely upvote if you could support each points